# Prism compatibility with UWP

Tags: mvvm, win-universal-app, prism

I recently started learning about Prism with UWP. Is there any specific new version of Prism to work with UWP? Can anyone share any tutorial for Prism with UWP in Visual Studio 2015??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a version of Prism for UWP.  Here is the project site:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism

There are samples here:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows

Comment: thank you so much!! glad that the author himself just answered me :)